# macOS cannot resolve LAN computer name, only via IP, but Windows can

Tags: macos, network, dns, nas

I notice the titled issue since I changed modem/router, it seems macOS depends on router's nameserver(192.168.1.1) to resolve LAN computer name.

At macOS: System Preference/Network/DNS, the DNS servers are ISP's external IPs. Here I added router IP(192.168.1.1) not solve the issue. If I ping to a computer within LAN, e.g. Synology DS720 (192.168.1.10):

```
> ping DS720   
ping: cannot resolve DS720: Unknown host
```

but ping 192.168.1.10 works fine. Yet I prefer to access the NAS server with its name instead of ip-adress for e.g. all home ioS devices. Strangely this issue of not able to resolve LAN computer name only happens at macOS or iOS devices. Windows 10 has no problem. Does it mean:

- macOS depends on router's nameserver for LAN?
- Is this related to WINS, yet macOS has it well

### Could anyone explain this and give a better solution than below?

My current awkward solution is setup a DNS server at DS720 and add its ip-address to macOS' network DNS server, additionally put DS720's IP address to /etc/hosts and manually  resolving the name as well. But this method is very inconvenient for all home macOS/iOS devices.

Thanks!

Comment: Try ping DS720.local

Comment: thanks! Is that related to [Bonjour support at router FW](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/why-cant-i-resolve-machine-names-on-my-lan-to-their-ip-address?rq=1) ? Still would prefer a unified solution for Win & mac/ios.

Comment: @mmmmmm also for http://DS720.local/WordPress always refer to w/o . local thus not accessible. But why Windows can do it?

Comment: I suspect that is a Windows configuration issue. .local is defined by an RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6762

Comment: This https://commaster.net/posts/how-resolve-multicast-dns-windows/ suggest MS Windows needs third party software to resolve .local